# FsCheck: Override generator for a type, but only in the context of a single parent generator

Tags: f#, fscheck, property-testing

I seem to often run into cases where I want to generate some complex structure, but a special variation with a member type generated differently.

For example, consider this tree

```ml
type Tree<'LeafData,'INodeData> =
    | LeafNode of 'LeafData
    | InternalNode of 'INodeData * Tree<'LeafData,'INodeData> list
```

I want to generate cases like

- No internal node is childless
- There are no leaf-type nodes
- Only a limited subset of leaf types are used

These are simple to do if I override all generation of a corresponding child type.
The problem is that it seems [register](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L195-195) is inherently a thread-level action, and there is no gen-local alternative.

For example, what I want could look like

```ml
let limitedLeafs =
  gen {
    let leafGen = Arb.generate<LeafType> |> Gen.filter isAllowedLeaf
    do! registerContextualArb (leafGen |> Arb.fromGen)
    return! Arb.generate<Tree<NodeType, LeafType>>
  }
```

This Tree example specifically can work around with some creative type shuffling, but that's not always possible.

It's also possible to use some sort of recursive map that enforces assumptions, but that seems relatively complex if the above is possible. I might be misunderstanding the nature of FsCheck generators though.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this kind of gen-local override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few options here - I'm assuming you're on FsCheck 2.x but keep scrolling for an option in FsCheck 3.

The first is the most natural one but is more work, which is to break down the generator explicitly to the level you need, and then put humpty dumpty together again. I.e don't rely on the type-based generator derivation so much - if I understand your example correctly that would mean implementing a [recursive generator](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/TestData.html#Generating-recursive-data-types)  - relying on `Arb.generate<LeafType>` for the generic types.

Second option - [`Config`](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/reference/fscheck-config.html) has an `Arbitrary` field which you can use to override `Arbitrary` instances. These overrides will take effect even if the overridden types are part of the automatically generated ones. So as a sketch you could try:

```
Check.One ({Config.Quick with Arbitrary = [| typeof<MyLeafArbitrary>) |]) (fun safeTree -> ...)
```

[More extensive example](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/tests/FsCheck.Test/Runner.fs#L22) which uses FsCheck.Xunit's `PropertyAttribute` but the principle is the same, set on the `Config` instead.

Final option! :) In FsCheck 3 (prerelease) you can configure this via a new (as of yet undocumented) concept `ArbMap` which makes the map from type to `Arbitrary` instance explicit, instead of this static global nonsense in 2.x (my bad of course. seemed like a good idea at the time.) The implementation is [here](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/fscheck3/src/FsCheck/FSharp.ArbMap.fs) which may not tell you all that much - the idea is that you put an `ArbMap` instance together which contains your "safe" generators for the subparts, then you `ArbMap.mergeWith` that safe map with `ArbMap.defaults` (thus overriding the default generators with your safe ones, in the resulting `ArbMap`) and then you use `ArbMap.arbitrary` or `ArbMap.generate` with the resulting map.

Sorry for the long winded explanation - but all in all that should give you the best of both worlds - you can reuse the generic union type generator in FsCheck, while surgically overriding certain types in that context.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer; I like the direction this is going! Two things 1. I'd be nice to directly register arbitraries like `ArbMap.withArb<'a> arb` without needing the intermediate type of static arb factory members. A quick look around looks like it'd be a fundamental change to TypeClass though. 2. I tested this out on a Tree<int, int>. LeafData was fine, but the Internal nodes didn't respect the overrides. It looks like the Tuple generator is relying on the default ArbMap and not the map with overrides.

Comment: I can provide a code sample demonstrating my issue if you'd like. Maybe in a GitHub issue?

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks - yes please open an issue if you can, also with the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

FsCheck [guidance](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/TipsAndTricks.html#Use-pattern-matching-instead-of-forAll-to-use-custom-generators) on this is:

> To define a generator that generates a subset of the normal range of values for an existing type, say all the even ints, it makes properties more readable if you define a single-case union case, and register a generator for the new type:

As an example, they suggest you could define arbitrary even integers like this:

```ml
type EvenInt = EvenInt of int with
    static member op_Explicit(EvenInt i) = i

type ArbitraryModifiers =
    static member EvenInt() = 
        Arb.from<int> 
        |> Arb.filter (fun i -> i % 2 = 0) 
        |> Arb.convert EvenInt int
        
Arb.register<ArbitraryModifiers>() |> ignore
```

You could then generate and test trees whose leaves are even integers like this:

```ml
let ``leaves are even`` (tree : Tree<EvenInt, string>) =
    let rec leaves = function
        | LeafNode leaf -> [leaf]
        | InternalNode (_, children) ->
            children |> List.collect leaves
    leaves tree
        |> Seq.forall (fun (EvenInt leaf) ->
            leaf % 2 = 0)

Check.Quick ``leaves are even``   // output: Ok, passed 100 tests.
```

To be honest, I like your idea of a "gen-local override" better, but I don't think FsCheck supports it.

Comment: These union wrappers are certainly good practice, and it works well in this tree case where the composed types are generic type parameters. Unfortunately, I also have structures where the composed types are not generic

Comment: I don't follow you. There's no need for the types to be generic. E.g. `EvenInt` is not generic.

Comment: EvenInt is passed to Tree as a generic type parameter. If, instead, LeafData were a fixed type then we would not be able to situationally replace it with a type that has a constrained generator (like was done with EvenInt)